# Correcting satellite image overlays for Rayshader

Tags: leaflet, rayshader

I'm trying to improve the look of Rayshader by overlaying more recent (higher detail) satellite imagery (that I'm getting from the {`leaflet`} packages) but the overlay doesn't match with the 3D rendering.

Ideally I'm looking for a **open-source** solution that can get global satellite imagery. Bonus points if you find finer detail data for my area of interest - Hawaii.

One method using {`geoviz`} and {`rayshader`} uses the `slippy_overlay()` function to create a number of overlay images from either **Mapbox** (*satellite*, *mapbox-streets-v8*, *mapbox-terrain-v2*, *mapbox-traffic-v1*, *terrain-rgb*, *mapbox-incidents-v1*) or **Stamen**. Although I found *mapbox-terrain-v2* the best it still lacks the detail I would like. Since it requires setting up an API for mapbox I just use **stamen/watercolor** below:

```
library(geoviz)
library(rayshader)

### Maui
lat = 20.785700
lon = -156.259204
square_km = 22
max_tiles = 10

dem <- mapzen_dem(lat, lon, square_km, max_tiles)

elev_matrix  = matrix(
        raster::extract(dem, raster::extent(dem), buffer=1000),
        nrow = ncol(dem),
        ncol = nrow(dem)
)

ambmat <- ambient_shade(elev_matrix, zscale = 30)
raymat <- ray_shade(elev_matrix, zscale = 30, lambert = TRUE)
watermap <- detect_water(elev_matrix)

overlay_img <-
        slippy_overlay(dem,
                       image_source = "stamen",
                       image_type = "watercolor",
                       png_opacity = 0.3,
                       max_tiles = max_tiles)

elev_matrix %>%
        sphere_shade(sunangle = 270, texture = "imhof4") %>%
        add_water(detect_water(elev_matrix), color="imhof4") %>%
        add_shadow(ray_shade(elev_matrix,zscale=3,maxsearch = 300),0.5) %>%
        add_shadow(ambmat,0.5) %>%
        add_overlay(overlay_img) %>%
        plot_3d(elev_matrix,
                solid = T,
                water = T,
                waterdepth = 0,
                wateralpha = 0.5,
                watercolor = "lightblue",
                waterlinecolor = "white",
                waterlinealpha = 0.5,
                zscale= raster_zscale(dem) / 3,
                fov=0,theta=135,zoom=0.75,phi=45, windowsize = c(1000,800))
```

[image]

I'm trying to adapt [Will Bishop](https://twitter.com/wcmbishop)'s [workflow for getting overlays with the `leaflet` package](https://wcmbishop.github.io/rayshader-demo/#introduction) but the result is very odd. Will's approach is a bit different as it fetches elevation data from USGS, which **doesn't have baythmetric elevation** which is **must** for me - so I used `geoviz`

```
library(leaflet)

# define bounding box with longitude/latitude coordinates
bbox <- list(
        p1 = list(long = -156.8037, lat = 20.29737),
        p2 = list(long = -155.7351, lat = 21.29577)
)

leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>% 
        addRectangles(
                lng1 = bbox$p1$long, lat1 = bbox$p1$lat,
                lng2 = bbox$p2$long, lat2 = bbox$p2$lat,
                fillColor = "transparent"
        ) %>%
        fitBounds(
                lng1 = bbox$p1$long, lat1 = bbox$p1$lat,
                lng2 = bbox$p2$long, lat2 = bbox$p2$lat,
        )
```

[image: bounding box]

What's the area of my hillshade from `geoviz`?

```
dim(dem)
780 780   1
```

Okay so the overlay image needs to be `780 x 780` so I modify the helper functions to download the overlay with the `World_Imagery` base map:

```
define_image_size <- function(bbox, major_dim = 780) {
        # calculate aspect ration (width/height) from lat/long bounding box
        aspect_ratio <- abs((bbox$p1$long - bbox$p2$long) / (bbox$p1$lat - bbox$p2$lat))
        # define dimensions
        img_width <- ifelse(aspect_ratio > 1, major_dim, major_dim*aspect_ratio) %>% round()
        img_height <- ifelse(aspect_ratio < 1, major_dim, major_dim/aspect_ratio) %>% round()
        size_str <- paste(img_width, img_height, sep = ",")
        list(height = img_height, width = img_width, size = size_str)
}

get_arcgis_map_image <- function(bbox, map_type = "World_Imagery", file = NULL, 
                                 width = 780, height = 780, sr_bbox = 4326) {
        require(httr)
        require(glue) 
        require(jsonlite)

        url <- parse_url("https://utility.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task/execute")

        # define JSON query parameter
        web_map_param <- list(
                baseMap = list(
                        baseMapLayers = list(
                                list(url = jsonlite::unbox(glue("https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/{map_type}/MapServer",
                                                                map_type = map_type)))
                        )
                ),
                exportOptions = list(
                        outputSize = c(width, height)
                ),
                mapOptions = list(
                        extent = list(
                                spatialReference = list(wkid = jsonlite::unbox(sr_bbox)),
                                xmax = jsonlite::unbox(max(bbox$p1$long, bbox$p2$long)),
                                xmin = jsonlite::unbox(min(bbox$p1$long, bbox$p2$long)),
                                ymax = jsonlite::unbox(max(bbox$p1$lat, bbox$p2$lat)),
                                ymin = jsonlite::unbox(min(bbox$p1$lat, bbox$p2$lat))
                        )
                )
        )

        res <- GET(
                url, 
                query = list(
                        f = "json",
                        Format = "PNG32",
                        Layout_Template = "MAP_ONLY",
                        Web_Map_as_JSON = jsonlite::toJSON(web_map_param))
        )

        if (status_code(res) == 200) {
                body <- content(res, type = "application/json")
                message(jsonlite::toJSON(body, auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE))
                if (is.null(file)) 
                        file <- tempfile("overlay_img", fileext = ".png")

                img_res <- GET(body$results[[1]]$value$url)
                img_bin <- content(img_res, "raw")
                writeBin(img_bin, file)
                message(paste("image saved to file:", file))
        } else {
                message(res)
        }
        invisible(file)
}
```

Now download the file, then load it

```
image_size <- define_image_size(bbox, major_dim = 780)

# fetch overlay image
overlay_file <- "maui_overlay.png"
get_arcgis_map_image(bbox, map_type = "World_Imagery", file = overlay_file,
                     # width = image_size$width, height = image_size$height, 
                     sr_bbox = 4326)

overlay_img <- png::readPNG("maui_overlay.png")
```

[image: satellite basemap]

Okay let's make the plot

```
elev_matrix %>%
        sphere_shade(sunangle = 270, texture = "imhof4") %>%
        add_water(detect_water(elev_matrix), color="imhof4") %>%
        add_shadow(ray_shade(elev_matrix,zscale=3,maxsearch = 300),0.5) %>%
        add_shadow(ambmat,0.5) %>%
        add_overlay(overlay_img, alphacolor = 1) %>%
        plot_3d(elev_matrix,
                solid = T,
                water = T,
                waterdepth = 0,
                wateralpha = 0.5,
                watercolor = "lightblue",
                waterlinecolor = "white",
                waterlinealpha = 0.5,
                zscale= raster_zscale(dem) / 3,
                fov=0,theta=135,zoom=0.75,phi=45, windowsize = c(1000,800))
```

As you can see the overlay image is rotated to the hillshade.

[image]

Now I'm also realizing that fetching satellite with a bounding box method isn't ideal when you're trying to show bathymatrix data. It would be ideal to subset this overlay somehow *programmatically* but I'll probably just end up using **inkscape** once I've figured out how to rotate the overlay.

I tried to use the {`magick`}'s `image_rotate()` function to no avail:

```
library(magick)
maui <- magick::image_read("maui_overlay.png")
image_rotate(maui, 30) # -> maui_30
# image_write(maui_30, path = "maui_overlay_30.png", format = "png")
```

But `magick` has changed the dimensions:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 7
  format width height colorspace matte filesize density
  <chr>  <int>  <int> <chr>      <lgl>    <int> <chr>  
1 PNG     1068   1068 sRGB       TRUE         0 38x38
```

And will give an error with `rayshader`:

```
overlay_img <- png::readPNG("maui_overlay_30.png")
elev_matrix %>%
        sphere_shade(sunangle = 270, texture = "imhof4") %>%
        add_water(detect_water(elev_matrix), color="imhof4") %>%
        add_shadow(ray_shade(elev_matrix,zscale=3,maxsearch = 300),0.5) %>%
        add_shadow(ambmat,0.5) %>%
        add_overlay(overlay_img, alphacolor = 1) %>%
        plot_3d(elev_matrix,
                solid = T,
                water = T,
                waterdepth = 0,
                wateralpha = 0.5,
                watercolor = "lightblue",
                waterlinecolor = "white",
                waterlinealpha = 0.5,
                zscale= raster_zscale(dem) / 3,
                fov=0,theta=135,zoom=0.75,phi=45, windowsize = c(1000,800))
```

> Error in add_overlay(., overlay_img, alpha = 0.8) : argument 3 matches multiple formal arguments

Answer (score 1):

The answer couldn't have been simpler... it needed to be transposed `overlay_img = aperm(overlay_img, c(2,1,3))`.